# unable to send email to valide users using codeigniter email library and google smtp settings

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i have this code in my public function inside my controllei am trying to validate users after registration by sending the user a mail.
After registration, the user doest not receive any email.

```
if ($validation_code)
                {

                    $email_template = $this->template_model->get_email_template(1);

                    if($email_template['status'] == "1") {

                        // build the validation URL
                        $encrypted_email = sha1($this->input->post('email', TRUE));
                        $validation_url  = base_url('user/validate') . "?e={$encrypted_email}&c={$validation_code}";


                        $site_name = $this->settings->site_name;
                        $name_user = $this->input->post('first_name') . ' ' . $this->input->post('last_name');

                        $rawstring = $email_template['message'];


                        $placeholders = array('[SITE_NAME]', '[CHECK_LINK]', '[NAME]');

                        $vals_1 = array($site_name, $validation_url, $name_user);


                        $str_1 = str_replace($placeholders, $vals_1, $rawstring);

                        $this -> email -> from($this->settings->site_email, $this->settings->site_name);
                        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email', TRUE));
                        //$this -> email -> to($user['email']);
                        $this -> email -> subject($email_template['title']);

                        $this -> email -> message($str_1);

                        $this->email->send();
                    }
```

No email is received when user is registered. i have tried using different ports.i have also enabled openssl in php.ini. Any help will be appreciated thanks.
the smtp settings

```
<?php
 $config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 //$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com ';
 $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxx';
 $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxx';
 $config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
 $config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
 $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
 $config['wrapchars'] = 76;
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
 $config['validate'] = FALSE;
 $config['priority'] = 3;
 $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
 $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
 $config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
 $config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
 ?>
```

Comment: email library already loaded